# Why is AddRewrite is redirecting (HTTP 301) in ASP.NET Core 7.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, http, url-rewriting

I'm adding a Rewrite rule in .NET ASP Core but it seems to be redirecting. I thought the whole point of `AddRewrite` was to be invisible to the HTTP client.

Here is my entire file:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MyProject.Preview.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpLogging();

var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(@"^p/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/w/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)","/preview/$1/workspace/$2/wwwroot",skipRemainingRules: true);

app.UseRewriter(options);

app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
{
   FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Pad").GetValue<string>(nameof(PadConfiguration.StorageRootPath)), "artifacts")),
   RequestPath = "/preview",
   DefaultFileNames =new List<string> { "index.html" }
});

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
   FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
   Path.Combine(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Pad").GetValue<string>(nameof(PadConfiguration.StorageRootPath)), "artifacts")),
   RequestPath = "/preview",
   ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
});


app.Run();
```

CURL output:

```
curl -I http://localhost:5033/p/d8f7i885d/w/583bdffe-09bd-4a03-8b4e-5006f743c617
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 04:52:22 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Location: http://localhost:5033/preview/d8f7i885d/workspace/583bdffe-09bd-4a03-8b4e-5006f743c617/wwwroot/
```

Why does `RewriteOptions` cause a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `RedirectToAppendTrailingSlash = false` solved the issue.

```cs
app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
{
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Pad").GetValue<string>(nameof(PadConfiguration.StorageRootPath)), "artifacts")),
        RequestPath = "/preview",
        RedirectToAppendTrailingSlash = false,
    DefaultFileNames =new List<string> { "index.html" }
});
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Pad").GetValue<string>(nameof(PadConfiguration.StorageRootPath)), "artifacts")),
        RequestPath = "/preview",
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        RedirectToAppendTrailingSlash = false
});
```